# Databricks - Read Streams - Delta Live Tables

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

I have a number of tables (with varying degrees of differences in schemas but with a common set of fields) that I would like to Union and load from bronze -> Silver in an incremental manner. So the goal is to go from multiple tables to a single table using DLT.

Example:

```
X_Events
Y_Events
.... N_Events 

To: All_Events
```

I am using a for loop to go through all the databases -> tables and then performing a `readStream` followed by a `UnionByName`.

However, if there is an additional table added/ modified dynamically that I need to process in the next run, I am getting a checkpoint error.

```
There are [8] sources in the checkpoint offsets and now there are 
[6] sources requested by the query. Cannot continue.
```

Is there a way to address this dynamically?

Should I build my own incremental logic? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [documented limitation of Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovery-semantics-after-changes-in-a-streaming-query):

> Changes in the number or type (i.e. different source) of input sources: **This is not allowed.**

But from your description I see that you may not need to use `UnionByName` - you can just have N independent streams that will write into the same table.  In case when you just do append to a table, [concurrent appends won't lead to a write conflicts](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/concurrency-control.html#write-conflicts) (each stream is independent!):

```
bronze 1  \
bronze 2   \
bronze 3    >--> append to a Silver table
.......... /
bronze N  /
```

In case if you need to do merges into a target table, or some other changes in it, you can still follow the same approach, by appending to an intermediate table, and then having a stream from it, and merging/updating the target table:

```
bronze 1  \
bronze 2   \
bronze 3    >--> append to an intermediate table --> merge into Silver
.......... /
bronze N  /
```